# Comparing two state variables in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to compare two state variables in React Native but apparently the conditional statement is not working on them. Here's my code

```
if(this.state.code===this.state.input)
         {
          alert('success');
            this.props.navigation.navigate('success_verification',{
             type:this.state.type,
             no:this.state.no
            });
         }
         else if(this.state.code!=this.state.input)
                this.props.navigation.navigate('failure_verification');
            
         else
          alert('NOT WORKING');
```

The result is the alert with 'NOT WORKING' message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Log `code` and `input` and `typeof code` and `typeof input` and you will see why the equality fails.

Comment: @windowsill YESS! I'm so dumb! Ofc it was a type issue, I changed === to == and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

The code that's on your question shouldn't even work. Try this one:

```js
if(this.state.code === this.state.input){

    alert('success');

    this.props.navigation.navigate('success_verification',{
        type:this.state.type,
        no:this.state.no
    });

} else if(this.state.code != this.state.input){

    this.props.navigation.navigate('failure_verification');
            
} else {
    alert('NOT WORKING');
}
```

Comment: use `console.log(this.state.code, this.state.input)` to see what's going on, and why it's different!

Comment: Yes I checked them, the values were same, but they were of different type, thats what I couldn't figure out. Thank you though.